# Skipping incompatible error when using arm-linux-gnueabihf on beaglebone black

Tags: c++, linux, arm, beagleboneblack, pocketsphinx

I am trying to compile pocketsphinx on my beaglebone black. However, i encountered a "Skipping incompatible error" during the building process through the use of Eclipse Luna. I tried linking -Lusr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf and also -lpthread -lm -lrt -ldl but it does not solve the error.

Compiling on my computer using gcc and g++ is ok. Just that after changing gcc and g++ to "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -std=c++11" and "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8 -std=c++11" does the problem arises.

This is what i get after compiling,

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a when searching for -lsphinxbase
>   skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.so when searching for -lsphinxad
>   skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.a when searching for -lsphinxad
>   skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so when searching for -lpocketsphinx
>   skipping incompatible /usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.a when searching for -lpocketsphinx
>   skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.so when searching for -lsphinxbase
>   skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libsphinxbase.a when searching for -lsphinxbase
>   skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.so when searching for -lsphinxad
>   skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libsphinxad.a when searching for -lsphinxad
>   skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.so when searching for -lpocketsphinx
>   skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libpocketsphinx.a when searching for -lpocketsphinx
>   make: *** [pocketsphinx2] Error 1
>   cannot find -lsphinxbase
>   cannot find -lsphinxad
>   cannot find -lpocketsphinx

Answer (score 2):

You have to  include the path to your  sphinx libraries in your compiler build  path:

-L"path/to/sphinx"

Once you have done that the unresolved symbols issue will have been corrected.

Comment: The required sphinx libraries are all included in my build path. I have no problem compiling it for my computer using gcc g++ command. It is only when i change the command to "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.8 -std=c++11" and "arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++-4.8 -std=c++11" to make it compatible with the beaglebone black does this error appears.